# Laravel - Route with multiple function

Tags: forms, laravel, function, routes

I have a problem with making a page to allow people to edit their profile, the thing is that I have 3 form on one page (one for profile settings, second for social settings and the 3rd for the account settings) and I made 3 controllers to control each one, the problem is that I can't call 3 controllers at the same time for one route...
here is my profile.blade.php:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['action' => ['ProfileController@updateProfile', 'id' => $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
...Some input to edit username, name, description settings...
{!! Form:close() !!}

{!! Form::model($user, ['action' => ['ProfileController@updateSocial', 'id' => $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
...Some input to set link to their social account...
{!! Form:close() !!}

{!! Form::model($user, ['action' => ['ProfileController@updateSettings', 'id' => $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
...Some input to update password or email...
{!! Form:close() !!}
```

Here is my web.php (routes):

```
Route::get('/profile/{urlid}', 'ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
Route::put('/profile/{urlid}', 'ProfileController@updateProfile');
Route::put('/profile/{urlid}', 'ProfileController@updateSocial');
Route::put('/profile/{urlid}', 'ProfileController@updateSettings');
```

And here is my ProfileController:

```
    public function updateProfile(Request $request, $urlid)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($urlid);
    $user->fname=$request->input('fname');
    $user->lname=$request->input('lname');
    $user->profile_title=$request->input('profile_title');
    $user->profile_resume=$request->input('profile_resume');         

    $user->save();

    return view('profile')->with([
            'user' => $user
        ]);
}

public function updateSocial(Request $request, $urlid)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($urlid);
    $user->perso_site=$request->input('perso_site');
    $user->linkedin=$request->input('linkedin');
    $user->twitter=$request->input('twitter');        

    $user->save();

    return view('profile')->with([
            'user' => $user
        ]);
}
public function updateSettings(Request $request, $urlid)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($urlid);
    $user->password=$request->input('password');
    $user->email=$request->input('email');      

    $user->save();

    return view('profile')->with([
            'user' => $user
        ]);
}
```

The thing is that all of those 3 forms are on the same page, and I get an error If I call the 3 functions at the same time

I tried with only one function, it work, everything is ok but with one function, only one form is working, I hope I will find some help, It's been almost 2 hours that I'm blocked with this problem..

So in conclusion: I have 3 forms on the same page, I need these 3 functions to make them work, but I can't call 3 functions for only one route.

Comment: I think you use same url. so use route name. Check my answer. Hope it will help you. And use post method.

Answer (score 0):

You route should looks like

```
Route::get('/profile/{urlid}', 'ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
Route::post('/profile/{profile_id}', 'ProfileController@updateProfile')->name('update_profile');
Route::post('/profile/{social_id}', 'ProfileController@updateSocial')->name('update_social');
Route::post('/profile/{settings_id}', 'ProfileController@updateSettings')->name('update_settings');
```

And your form in blade

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('update_profile', ['profile_id' => $user->id]), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"]) !!}

//....
{!! Form:close() !!}


{!! Form::open(['url' => route('update_social', ['social_id' => $user->id]), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"]) !!}

//....
{!! Form:close() !!}



{!! Form::open(['url' => route('update_settings', ['settings_id' => $user->id]), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"]) !!}

//....
{!! Form:close() !!}
```

In your function

```
public function updateProfile(Request $request, $urlid)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    return $data; //check what you pass from the form...
    //then after remove return
    $user = User::findOrFail($urlid);
    if($user)
    {
        $user->fname=$data['fname'];
        $user->lname=$data['lname']
        $user->profile_title=$data['profile_title']
        $user->profile_resume=$data['profile_resume']      

        $user->update();

        return view('profile')->with([
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }
    return "User not found";

}
```

And the first form for you: https://pastebin.com/JznW20iy
Your second two form: https://pastebin.com/NuDTtvFR

and function

```
public function updateSocial(Request $request, $urlid)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    return $data; //check what you pass from the form...
    //then after remove return
    $user = User::findOrFail($urlid);
    if($user)
    {
        $user->perso_site=$data['perso_site'];
        $user->linkedin=$data['linkedin']
        $user->twitter=$data['twitter']    

        $user->update();

        return view('profile')->with([
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }
    return "User not found";

}

public function updateSettings(Request $request, $urlid)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    return $data; //check what you pass from the form...
    //then after remove return
    $user = User::findOrFail($urlid);
    if($user)
    {
        $user->email=$data['email'];
        $user->password=$data['newPass']     

        $user->update();

        return view('profile')->with([
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }
    return "User not found";

}
```

Comment: Hello! First, thank you for answering my question! I'm going to check if this work and I'll tell you! :)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, when I press the button submit it give an error with 'No message', I tried with all the 3 forms :(

Comment: return somethings from your function to check that your function is call or not.

Comment: I forgot to change Route::put with Route::post as you wrote, thank you It is good but I have the same problem that below, If I click submit for the form 2 for example, It submit all of the 3 forms with the data 'null', So I have an error because I don't want null data in my db, but thank you anyway :)

Comment: Put some code that contain the form. your submit button should belongs to inside the form.

Comment: Here is the full code of all the 3 forms: https://pastebin.com/TAYWmGde

Comment: Check your first form with my ['profile_id' => $user->id].  change the name attribute of the button. you use same name of the button. Here there is no need to use name attribute of the button. you cane remove the button name form all three.

Comment: use <input type="text" class='form-control' name="fname" value="{{ $user->fname}}" /> insted of {!! Form::text('fname', $user->fname, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!} and change hole the input field like this. Now problem in your input field. Not route controller or form.

Comment: I changed it, still have the same error, I tried to change my twitter link so in the second form and I have the error that data from the first form can't be null... Here is the error: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'fname' cannot be null (SQL: update `users` set `fname` = , `lname` = , `profile_resume` = , `profile_title` = , `updated_at` = 2017-11-09 18:38:10 where `id` = 1)`

Comment: It still work when I edit the profile informations but when I try to edit the social links, I have this new error: "Undefined index: fname"

Comment: You are doing very little mistake again and again. You should learn very basic first before doing this project. But i did again for you. Check my edited answer.

Comment: I'll check this thank you, yes I'm actually re learning all the bacis because I have some things that I don't understood, thank again and have a nice day/night !

Answer (score 0):

Seperate your url's and set your Routes like taht:

```
Route::get('/profile/{urlid}', 'ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
Route::post('/profile/{urlid}', 'ProfileController@updateProfile')->name('update_profile');
Route::post('/profile/social/{urlid}', 'ProfileController@updateSocial')->name('update_social');
Route::post('/profile/settings/{urlid}', 'ProfileController@updateSettings')->name('update_settings');
```

and in the form blade use the route function for detting the action url like that ...

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('update_profile', ['urlid' => $user->id]), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"]) !!}
...Some input to edit username, name, description settings...
{!! Form:close() !!}


{!! Form::open(['url' => route('update_social', ['urlid' => $user->id]), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"]) !!}
...Some input to set link to their social account...
{!! Form:close() !!}


{!! Form::open(['url' => route('update_settings', ['urlid' => $user->id]), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"]) !!}
...Some input to update password or email...
{!! Form:close() !!}
```

Comment: It work but only for the first form (update_profile) Because after, If I try to change the link to the social media (which is form 2) It automatically submit the form 1 too (profile) with all input = null, So I have an error because I can't enter null data in these column. Each time I click submit, it send all of the 3 forms  data...